# Multiple log4j.properties files

Tags: java, log4j

This might not seem a valid question but I have a requirement here. Below is my project structure:

```
common (built as a jar)
module-1 (war, includes common.jar in its classpath)
module-2 (war, includes common.jar in its classpath)
module-3 (war, includes common.jar in its classpath)
module-4 (war, includes common.jar in its classpath)
```

The deployment is like below:

module-1 and module-2 is on one server and module-3 and module-4 on another.

The requirement is to have two separate log files(one for each server). So, the way to achieve this is put the `log4j.properties` (definitely with different names) in the common module and copy the required properties file to the respective server's conf folder.

I am not sure, if I can have the logging properties file with different names, if it is possible, please help me with a direction to do so.

**EDIT** To make this easier, if you anyone can tell me if I can use a different name for the `log4j.properties` file and how to load it to the server, I would be able to achieve the rest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally fixed this issue, and yes there is a way of using a name different than `log4j.properties` for the log4j configuration properties file.

We can name it whatever we want say `mylog4j.properties`. For the JVM to pick this up we need to pass an argument to the JVM like below:

`-Dlog4j.configuration=mylog4j.properties`

When running applications using eclipse, you can do this by going to Run Configurations -> Arguments Tab -> VM Arguments and add the property 
`-Dlog4j.configuration=mylog4j.properties`

Comment: Can this be set in the code as opposed to on the command line?

Comment: In Java: System.setProperty("log4j.configuration", "mylog4j.properties")